# NodeJS (back-end) receive data from POST call then how to show in ReactJS (front-end)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm new to NodeJS/ReactJS.
I've got a NodeJS backend that receive a JSON POST from an external resource. I'm able to show data in console in express-async-router request.

This is my NodeJS back-end

```
const AsyncRouter = require("express-async-router").AsyncRouter;
const router = AsyncRouter();
const jsonParser = require("body-parser").json({limit: "500kb"});
const validate = require("express-validation");
const schema = require("./schema");

router.use(jsonParser);

router.post("/exist", async (req, res) => {
  // console.log("Request");
  // console.log(req);
  return res.status(200).json({
    body: req.body,
    msg: "Ciao"
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

This code print in console the POST request body.

I would show this data in ReactJS frontend but I've got no idea how to do it.

What is the best practice to achieve my goal?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to show what posted on the frontend?

Comment: this is server side code. possibly you are calling this route from your rest client e.g. `localhost:3000/exists` and it will return a json back. This json response is for your clients. While you are working with react.js, you have to use reacts' api for e.g. https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html. `Use fetch react's api to call this route and bind data in react` Straightforward :)

Comment: https://alligator.io/react/axios-react/

Comment: @code_bash: yes! I need to pass POST data to my frontend but I don't know how to

Comment: @Vineet localhost:3000/exist doensn't work. I try fetch inside my `ComponentDidMount(fetch(Config.ip + '/api/anagrafe/exist'))` but console.log show this error: **GET http://myIp/api/anagrafe/exist 404 (Not Found)**. I try to add GET route to exist but it haven't the data. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use Fetch, Axios or superagent module to make api call.
please refer this for more details
https://reactjs.org/community/data-fetching.html

https://daveceddia.com/ajax-requests-in-react/

below is a sample react component to make HTTP call on button click event

```
import axios from 'axios'

class App extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      username: ''
    }

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick () {
    axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/sandeepp2016')
      .then(response => this.setState({username: response.data.name}))
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className='button__container'>
        <button className='button' onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Me</button>
        <p>{this.state.username}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default App
```

Comment: Hi @Sandeep Patel, I'm been able to do GET/POST call after a button click. In this case, there is an external website that do POST to my back-end and I need to precompile my front-end form with this POST data

Comment: you can make api call in componentDidMount component lifecycle method and fill up form input field

Answer (score 0):

You'll need your React frontend to query the Node backend. The simplest way to do this is using the Fetch API, which is well-documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

You'll also need to set up a route in your Node backend to accept the fetch request from the frontend and return the desired resources. The express-async-router docs are probably the best place to start.

Comment: Hi @davidfloyd91, how to save data in Node backend to retrieve them with fetch request from the frontend?

Comment: Are you using a database? You might be able to accomplish what you need without one, but here's a Node-MySQL tutorial to get you started if you do choose to persist the data https://hackernoon.com/setting-up-node-js-with-a-database-part-1-3f2461bdd77f